# how to rename variables in datasummary (rmarkdown, latex pdf)

Tags: latex, r-markdown, summary

I am unable to rename the variables in datasummary. I don't think it has an option to do that. Any tips?
[image: My output]

```
summary_vars <- as.formula(glue("any_prio + any_prio_on + any_prio_off + war_prio + war_prio_on + 
  war_prio_off + war_col + war_inc + war + GPCP + GPCP_g + GPCP_g_l + gdp_g + 
  gdp_g_l + y_0 + polity2l + polity2l_6 + deml + ethfrac + relfrac + Oil + 
  mtnest + lpopl1 + tot_100_g ~ mean*Arguments(na.rm = TRUE) + sd*Arguments(na.rm = TRUE) + N"))

TableA1 <- datasummary(data = mss_rep, summary_vars, booktabs = T,
                      fmt = 2,
                      col.names = c("", "Mean", "Standard Deviation", "Observations"),
                      caption = "DESCRIPTIVE STATISTICS") |> 
          kable_styling() |>
                   pack_rows("A. Civil Conflict Measures (1981–99)", 1, 9) |>
                   pack_rows("B. Rainfall Measures (1981–99)", 10, 12) |> 
                   pack_rows("C. Economic Growth", 13, 14) |>
                   pack_rows("D. Country Characteristics", 15, 24)

TableA1
```

Comment: It is better to provide a minimal working example using data even accessible to anyone (e.g. built-in data sets such as `mtcars` and `iris`, or simulation data that you created), so that your helpers in this community can easily and promptly post answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the `datasummary` as a dataframe, do the renaming and apply a new `kbl` afterwards, e.g.

```
library(modelsummary)
library(kableExtra)

summary_df <- datasummary(mpg + cyl ~ mean, data = mtcars, output = "data.frame", fmt = 2)

# renaming
summary_df[,1] <- c("MPG", "CYL")

summary_df |> 
  kbl(booktabs = TRUE) |> 
  kable_styling() |>
  pack_rows("A. Civil Conflict Measures (1981–99)", 1, 2)
```

[image]